# Update inherited production server

Tags: debian, updates, webserver

I recently took over the development and server maintenance of a website hosted on a Debian VPS installation. I realise now, that the server haven't been updated in ages. There are updates for Nginx, Postgresql, libxml and about 20 other packages, some of which are critical to keep the site running and some that I'm not sure if they are needed or not.

I realise these packages that are not updated might pose a significant security risk. Being inexperienced in server maintenance however, I am not sure on how to go about the task of updating the packages in a safe way. If something goes wrong, I will need to revert until I can find a fix to keep the website online. Running `apt-get upgrade` seems like a big risk in itself.

Do you have any tips that could be useful in a situation such as this? What would you do? Is there a way to 'version control' the packages? Would you update them one by one?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian people make an enormous effort at assuring consistency of the packages provided through their repos. This is the whole point in having a version called **stable**. So, to the extent that you are interested in repo-distributed packages, you have nothing to fear.
Should you wish to know more, and seek further reassurance, you may wish to read [this popular talk](http://upsilon.cc/~zack/talks/2013/20130628-normale.pdf) given by the three-time former Debian Project leader, Stefano Zacchiroli. Don't be put off by the title in Italian, the rest of the talk is in English.

However, there may be some cause of concern regarding any non-repo software installed on your machine, because there is of course no assurance that you may find a version running with the new kernel and the new lib's. The usual places where custom software is installed are

```
  /opt, /usr/local, /usr/share
```

You may also double-check the debian packages installed by means of

```
  dpkg -l | more
```

Notice that some custom software may be installed via a Debian package, but not all custom software need be installed this way.

Answer (score 1):

Icll give you two answers at the price of one.

1. If you have access to the hypervisor the vps runs on you may be able to take a snapshot before you upgrade the system. Tjen simply upgrade the machine and be prepared to roll back the snapshot if you crap out.
2. You should always have a disaster plan for important machines. Disks fail - and sometimes trusted parties arn't... I'd setup a new machine and document exactly how it was done. That way you can easily test changes without risking production and you always have a fallback in case the production environment is destroyed.